# Is there a way to query in Marketing Cloud to check how many contacts enter a journey in the last 30 days?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

Currently, we are using the specific journey's history to check the Entry Results for the last 30 days. However, I was wondering if we could query this using Automation Studio in SFMC to automate this process and run the query on a weekly basis to check the counts? The current process that we follow requires manual intervention as going to every journey and check the details.

Comment: Not really, your best option to automate it would be to use the journey history API route: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/27/get-journey-history-by-filtering-the-definition-id-via-api/

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a TimeStamp field (*filled with GETDATE() by default*) on my Journeys data extension entry source and set up an weekly query automation counting those with dates added to the data extension within the last 30 days.

Would you be able to use that approach?